# Octave plots: set box off by default, override factory defaults

Tags: octave

I seek to override a default setting in Octave concerning plots. For instance, I always set `box off;` when plotting, so I would like to set the box off by default. Perhaps `factoryaxesbox` is the involved setting (are those factory settings documented anywhere?).

When I see a setting returned by `get(0, "factory")`, how can I assign a new default to override this?

I have been through this section of the Octave manual, [section 15.3.5: Managing Default Properties](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Managing-Default-Properties.html), but it says little and I find it rather confusing. Object type, root object, child object, … Huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after some amount of trial and error.

The name of available properties for plots are those returned by `get(0, "factory")`, *without* the `factory` prefix. In order to override any of these, you must prefix the property name with `default`, in the format `set(0, "defaultNameOfProperty", "newsetting")`.

To set `box off` by default for all plots: 
`set(0, "defaultaxesbox", "off")`

Before doing this, if you check for the existence of this property `defaultaxesbox`, using `get(0, "default")`, you will find nothing, making you wonder if you can set a setting which does not seem to exist. After the assignment has been made with `set()`, it will show up in `get(0, "default")`.

If the first argument of `set()` was `gca()` or some other number, then replace zero with that in the above `get()`.